# Regex appending to one of the words

Tags: javascript, regex

Given:

```
Ya its a great day.
```

Find (Do both in 1 regex statement)

```
Ya => Ya + cat
great => great + cat
```

**How can I do something like this?**

```
"Ya its a great day".replace(/found=(Ya|great)/g, found + " cat");
```

Output:

```
Ya cat its a great cat day.
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Ya its a great day".replace(/(Ya|great)/g,  "$1 cat");
```

Output:

```
Ya cat its a great cat day
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mL9R/)

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) by [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773398/regex-appending-to-one-of-the-words#comment29388917_19773398)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the found match using referencing: $1 $2 and so on

```
"Ya its a great day".replace(/(Ya|great)/g, "$1 cat");
```